# How to respond to post request in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My client-side code is something like:

```
let data = "Some data";

let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
let link = new URL("http://someurl.com");
link.searchParams.set("data", data);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    //some code
  }
}
request.open("POST", link, true);
request.send();
```

How can I retrieve "data" on the sever with node.js?

Comment: First you need to create api in backend. Than you can fetch data from those api in frontend

Comment: have a look at fetch.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is wouldn't be simple.
First of all, you should use [createServer](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) from one of the native libraries [http](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/http.html) or [https](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/https.html). Also, you should know how does [stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/stream.html) and [events](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/events.html) work in Node.js

```js
const https = require('https');
const srv = https.createServer(...);

const SRV_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
const SRV_PORT = 5000;
const MAX_PAYLOAD = 2048;

// You should provide your custom code for these events
srv.on('connection', onClientConnection);
srv.on('request', onClientRequest);
srv.on('clientError', onClientError);
srv.on('close', onServerClose);

// Start listening...
srv.listen(SRV_PORT, SRV_HOST, onStartListening);

function onClientRequest(req, res) {
    const connectionId = `${req.client.remoteAddress}:${req.client.remotePort}`;
    const dataPocket = {
        chunks: [],
        bytes: 0
    };

    req.on('data', chunk => onClientData.call(req, res, chunk, dataPocket));
    req.on('end', onClientEnd.bind(this, req, res, dataPocket));
    req.on('error', onClientRequestError);
    res.on('close', onClientClose.bind(res, connectionId));
}

function onClientData(res, chunk, dataPocket) {
    dataPocket.bytes += chunk.length;

    if (dataPocket.bytes <= MAX_PAYLOAD) {
        dataPocket.chunks.push(chunk);
    } else {
        const message = `Data limit exceeded. Maximum ${MAX_PAYLOAD} bytes are expected`;
        const error = new Error(message);
        error.code = 'ECONNRESET';
        return this.emit('error', error);
    }
}

function onClientEnd(req, res, dataPocket) {
    const data = collectData(req, dataPocket.chunks);

    // Process your data here
    const responseData = { success: true, data: data };
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(responseData);

    // Set headers and status
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.statusCode = 200;

    // Send data
    res.end(jsonData);

    // Cleanup data
    dataPocket.chunks = [];
    dataPocket.bytes = 0;
}
```

You can look an example in my [GitHub profile](https://github.com/yukal/portmone/blob/https/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the http package. Nowadays you can use an async iterator on streams. That makes reading the data and error handling more easy and less likely to cause memory leaks.

```js
const { createServer } = require('http');

createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    req.setEncoding('utf-8');
    (async (readable) => {
      for await (let chunk of readable) {
        // do here with the data what you want
        console.log(chunk);
      }
      res.writeHead(201);
      res.end();
    })(req).catch((err) => {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end()
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

If you are interested in piping the output to another stream,  you could also use the [pipeline method](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback) for that.

You can also check [this repl](https://repl.it/@bluebrown/handle-post-request-with-native-http-module#README.md) to get a live demo.